# Shared Element Transition from a recyclerView Item to another activity's recyclerView Item?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I am not sure,  **if this is possible or not** but I have RecyclerView in Activity A. On clicking any of the item, it should open a new Activity (let's say Activity B), which is again containing a RecyclerView.

So, I want to achieve a Shared Element Transition relationship from Activity A's any item to Activity B's first item, which is always the item clicked in my previous Activity A. And then on scrolling in Activity B, we should be able to see all the other elements, which is fetched from different API source.

Comment: Is it mandatory to show the item which is clicked in activity A in the recyclerview of activity B? If not then create a similar layout at the top of recyclerview and rest items of activity B to be added in recycler view.

Comment: It is mandatory to show that element as the first element. @bhagyawantbiradar